# BS4 .decompose выводит None

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Провожу парсинг онлайн магазина.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import lxml

bookInfo = []

with open("C:/Users/user/Desktop/Alib.html") as file:
    src = file.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")

book = soup.find_all("p")
count = 0

for item in book:
    count += 1
    if 4 <= count <= 63:
        all_data = item
        all_data = all_data.b.decompose()
        print(all_data)
```

`.decompose` выводит None. Входные данные:

```html
<p>
    <b>
        Valar morghulis, Valar dohaeris
    </b>
    Valar morghulis, Valar dohaeris
    <br/>
    (Читайте описание продавца
    <a href="">
        Valar morghulis, Valar dohaeris
    </a>
    , Москва.) Цена: 66000 руб.
    <a href="">
        <b>
            Купить
        </b>
    </a>
    <br/>
    Valar morghulis, Valar dohaeris
    <br/>
    Состояние: Отличное
    <br/>
    Смотрите:
    <a href="">
        Фото
    </a>
</p>
```

Возможно, есть способ добраться до текста вне вложенных тегов по-другому, но это единственное решение, которое я нашёл.

Comment: А что Вы ожидаете получить в результате работы метода `decompose()`?
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose

Comment: И еще, Вы когда просите помочь с парсингом давайте ссылки на страницы (ресурсы) которые пытаетесь парсить. Ответ получите гораздо быстрее, потому как гораздо проще пойти к источнику посмотреть код страницы и выдать Вам готовое решение, чем продираться через толщу нагромождений наверченных в вашем примере.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65471473/how-to-scrape-nested-text-between-tags-using-beautifulsoup